# Nothing happen when uploading image laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

when I am trying to upload an image there is no error being shown or anything coming out. All it does was return me back to the create1.blade.php. When I try to use dd, it also doesn't show anything as well(maybe I put it wrongly or something not sure, still learning about it)

Here are my codes:

Controller:

```
public function create1(){

return view('create1');
}

public function store1(Request $request){
     $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {
    $image = $request->file('input_img');
    $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
    $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
    $this->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Image Upload successfully');
    }
}
```

create1.blade.php

```
         <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}">

         {{  csrf_field()  }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input data-preview="#preview" name="input_img" type="file" id="imageInput">
            <img class="col-sm-6" id="preview"  src="" ></img>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag!

This is allow to upload the file!

For example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Hope this fixed your issue!

Comment: tks for the reply, but after using enctype, I got this error "Method [save] does not exist" any idea?

Comment: Issue is in `$this->save();` line

Comment: I used dd($request all()); and I got this, array:2 [▼ "_token" => "WEjAiIuSqkIlR9qVT5wvqLA3CAlRoZPA5Avrlrqx" "input_img" => UploadedFile {#228 ▼ -test: false -originalName: "58832_300x300.jpg" -mimeType: "image/jpeg" -size: 3801 -error: 0 #hashName: null path: "C:\xampp\tmp" filename: "phpF13D.tmp" basename: "phpF13D.tmp" pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF13D.tmp" extension: "tmp" realPath: false writable: false readable: false executable: false file: false dir: false link: false } ]

Comment: creating new record

Comment: Where you create new object to create new one?

Comment: Sry I don't understand the question, could you repeat agn in more simple terms

Comment: I think you need to do `$image = new your_model_name();` after `if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {` and then you save like `$image->save();` It's simple!

Comment: Oh that what you mean, I see, I forgotten to put in the model, thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157266/discussion-between-blastme-and-hiren-gohel).

Comment: for some reason it didn't work, the same error appear agn

Comment: ohh, I'm getting the same error again after putting my model, do I need to create a database for it to store the image?

Comment: Can you please check this link, this helps you: http://www.expertphp.in/article/how-to-upload-save-and-display-file-from-database-in-laravel-52

Comment: Yes, if you want to save it to db, you need to create new column in your db table! Hope you understand!

Comment: Oh it finally work, all I needed to do was to remove the save function, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Np, so you only want to move image to public directory! Glad i could help you:)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}">
```

here you are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Put it in form like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and try again.

Comment: Hi, tks for the quick reply, I am getting this error now after using adding that in "Method [save] does not exist."

Comment: Check this line `$this->save();`, the error is here now

Comment: I used dd($request all()); and I got this, array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "WEjAiIuSqkIlR9qVT5wvqLA3CAlRoZPA5Avrlrqx"
  "input_img" => UploadedFile {#228 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "58832_300x300.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 3801
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
    filename: "phpF13D.tmp"
    basename: "phpF13D.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF13D.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]

Comment: So shouldn't there be no problem?